# google chrome - gmail text window gets very wide beyond screen view, very frustrating

Tags: google-chrome

My Gmail mail window getting very wide, off the screen wide. A person replied with an answer and said to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + roll down and then reset.

But can someone please explain what "roll down" means? I have not "roll down" key on my computer and don't see any explanation when I google it. I am having this wide screen problem in Google Chrome ...

I have the bar at the bottom but I would really like a way to resize the gmail text window ... when I resize the chrome window, it just hides the text in  my gmail message that I am typing.

Comment: Simple workaround to this 6 year old problem:  Go to Reply to (<-- V) menu above edit box.  Select "Change Subject" from the menu.  This puts you into the pop-up editor and margins work!  Sorry, they won't let me "answer" this problem...

Answer (score 2):

Change the Display Mode (gear in the upper right) to Touch-enabled then change it back to your preferred Display mode.

Comment: that solution does not work for me, window is still too wide, seems to be some emails forcing the window to be wide

Answer (score 0):

The action you're referring to is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scrolling down on your mouse's scroll wheel. This will zoom out and hopefully make your content fit.

A similar method of the same action would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Without a mouse to "roll" down to change display size, you can press and hold Ctrl while you press the keys with "+" or "-" (plus or minus signs) to increase or decrease size.

Answer (score 0):

@David Worry suggested a work-around of using the pop-up editor.
This fixes the width problem for a new message being composed.

However, when replying to a message, the original message is still too wide, and hard to read.

I found a simple work-around for viewing the original message, while writing a reply:
copy-and-paste the original message into Word.

This way I can read the original message in Word, while writing a reply in the pop-up window.

In my test for this, Word displayed the original formatting ok, e.g., bulleted lists, underlining, hyperlinks, etc.

This is a hack solution, but I haven't found a good solution, after some looking around.